# Bind an array to a Knockout style binding

Tags: javascript, arrays, knockout.js, data-binding, binding

I have an observableArray of css properties. The elements are like this:

`[{
   "--border-color": "red" //(colorName = observable - colorValue = observable)
   ...
}]`

I want to avoid using the `foreach` to create multiple `<style>` tags.

I need something that can do a thing like this:

```
data-bind="style: colorStyles"  //colorStyles = array mentioned above
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you accidentally swap the `{` and `[`? Your css properties format is invalid.

Comment: my bad bro, i'll fix it right away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Step 1: merging the array of properties in to a single object

Many ways to do this, of which I prefer using `Object.assign` and the spread syntax:

```
const mergedStyle = Object.assign({}, ...colorStyles);
```

For other (more browser compatible) ways, google/search for "Merging an array of objects".

### Step 2: Setting the styles

Judging by the looks of your property name, you're using [custom css properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) which, as far as I know, are not supported by the [default `style` binding](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/style.js)...

You could write a quick custom binding that uses `element.style.setProperty` internally to add support:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.varStyle = {
  init: (el, va) => {
    ko.computed(() => {
      Object.entries(ko.unwrap(va()))
        .forEach(([prop, val]) => {
          el.style.setProperty(prop, val);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

Make sure to check your edge cases.

### A demo:

The first element renders the regular, unchanged `<div>` style. The second one uses the default `style` binding, which fails to update the custom property. The third element uses the custom binding, updating both the `color` as well as the `background-color`.

```js
// Our style objects:
const allStyles = ko.observableArray([
  { "color": "white" },
  { "--my-color": "red" }
]);

const mergedStyle = ko.pureComputed(
  () => Object.assign({}, ...allStyles())
);

// Our custom binding
ko.bindingHandlers.varStyle = {
  init: (el, va) => {
    ko.computed(() => {
      Object.entries(ko.unwrap(va()))
        .forEach(([prop, val]) => {
          el.style.setProperty(prop, val);
        });
    });
  }
}

ko.applyBindings({
  myStyle: mergedStyle
});
```

```css
div {
  --my-color: green;
  background: var(--my-color);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="style: {}">Hello world</div>
<div data-bind="style: myStyle">Hello world</div>
<div data-bind="varStyle: myStyle">Hello world</div>
```